# Box some equations inside align

Tags: math-mode, align

I'm trying to make something like this:
[image: goal]

But I have just can't figure out how. I have tried with empheq and `tikz`, but I can't get it to work with only some boxes inside `align`. I have also tried with `\boxed` and `\Aboxed`, no success either.

I have a few example of what I have tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
& 1 &(p \wedge q) \wedge r && \text{premise} \\
& 2 & p \wedge q && \wedge_e_1 1 \\
& 3 & r && \wedge_e_2 1 \\
& 4 & p && \wedge_e_1 2 \\
& 5 & q && \wedge_e_2 2 \\
& 6 & q \wedge r && \wedge_i 5,3 \\
& 7 & p \wedge (q \wedge r) && \wedge_1 4,6
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This gives me something like the format but no boxes. Then I thought I could ditch the first column by just numerate the equations on the left with: `\documentclass[12pt, leqno]{article}`, but I have no idea on have I'm going to box some of the lines.

So I hope one of you experts can help me make something like this in Latex.

EDIT:
I'm getting a bit closer my goal, I have now succesfully mad one box:

```
$$
\begin{tabular}{ccl}
1 & \neg p \rightarrow p & \text{premise} \\
\cline{2-3}
2 & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\neg p} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\text{assumption}} \\
3 & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{p} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\rightarrow_e 2,1} \\
4 & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\bot} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\neg_e 3,2} \\
\cline{2-3}
5 & \neg \neg p & \neg_i 2-4 \\
6 & p & \neg \neg_e 5 
\end{tabular}
$$
```

So the question is now. How do I make a Box inside the Box?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: As long as it looks something like the image, then I don't really care how it's done. I just normally use `align` to equations.

Comment: In your edit, where exactly do you want to put the first box and the second? You may use the MWE I provided to get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a MWE using the `tikzmark` library.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}   

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{2em}}ll}
        1 & $p\wedge q\rightarrow r$ & premise\\
        2 & \pgfmark{a}$p$ & assumption\\
        3 & \pgfmark{c}$q$ & assumption\\
        4 & $p\wedge q$ & $\wedge i\ 2,3$\pgfmark{d}\\
        5 & $q\rightarrow r$ & $\rightarrow i\ 3-5$\pgfmark{b}\\
        6 & $p\rightarrow (q\rightarrow r)$ & $\rightarrow i\ 2-6$
    \end{tabular}
    \tikz [remember picture]{ 
    \draw [overlay,->] ([shift={(-1em,2ex)}]pic cs:a) rectangle ([shift={(1.5em,-1.25ex)}]pic cs:b);
    \draw [overlay,->] ([shift={(-0.75em,2ex)}]pic cs:c) rectangle ([shift={(2.5em,-1.25ex)}]pic cs:d);}
\end{document}
```

On a quick note, since most of your content is to be in mathmode, you can use an array instead of a tabular. I have edited your example below:

[image]

```
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
$\begin{array}{ccl}
1 & \neg p \rightarrow p & \text{premise} \\
\cline{2-3}
2 & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\neg p} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\text{assumption}} \\
3 & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\pgfmark{e}p} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\rightarrow_e 2,1\pgfmark{f}} \\
4 & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\bot} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\neg_e 3,2} \\
\cline{2-3}
5 & \neg \neg p & \neg_i 2-4 \\
6 & p & \neg \neg_e 5 
\end{array}$}
\tikz [remember picture]{% 
    \draw [overlay,->] ([shift={(-1.5em,2ex)}]pic cs:e) rectangle ([shift={(2em,-1.25ex)}]pic cs:f);}
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver. I used the array solution you came up with. Brilliant. i would never have figured this out myself

Comment: @Kasperhogh Glad it helped. Don't hesitate to ask any questions here at TeX.SX and happy TeXing!